# How can I encrypt files on a backup server with a password only?

Tags: encryption

I backup (rsync) my personal files to a remote Debian box.
The server runs Debian stable and the files are stored in an external hard disk.

Once the files are transferred, I want to encrypt them (or the whole external disk), using a password only, not a keyfile.

The reasons are for simplicity, mostly.
I also want to be able to provide the password to someone trusted (and not necessarily technically experienced), in case they need to access the files.

I'm aware of the options detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/251174/how-to-do-rsync-like-encrypted-backup) like Duplicity, but I already use a custom rsync script to handle incremental backups, interrupted connections and some other things.

So, I would prefer to continue using my script, but just add some basic encryption.

Is there a user-friendly, maintained encryption method I can use?

Comment: stackexchange suggested the related
[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506832/119298), to encrypt an
existing filesystem inplace. You can use a password or a key file with `cryptsetup`.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt ... on the fly during transfer (i.e. encrypted at destination server only) ... or ... perform transfer first, then encrypt after full replication on destination server (again only encrypted at destination) ... or ... do you want to encrypt locally before performing the transfer (i.e. no snooping can intercept contents of packets) ? You could create an encrypted duplicate of each file locally pre-transfer.  That way, you don't have to worry that the remote has room to perform the encryption.  Otherwise, dedicate (i.e. format) a partition with encryption password.