# Convert an existing filesystem partition to one encrypted with dmsetup

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-encryption, dm-crypt

I am developing an embedded ARM-based Linux device, which is initially programmed with a non-encrypted ext4 filesystem image. On first boot, an initramfs script uses `resize2fs` followed by `cryptsetup-reencrypt` to LUKS-encrypt the root partition in-place. (See eg [encryption - Is there a way to encrypt disk without formatting it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444931/is-there-a-way-to-encrypt-disk-without-formatting-it).) That strategy has been working fine.

However, now I want to change to using `dmsetup` to encrypt the partition with "plain" dm-crypt, rather than using `cryptsetup`. The reason is, to use a key management system built-in to the processor (CAAM on NXP i.MX8), and apparently it's necessary to use `dmsetup`.

My question is, is there some functional equivalent of `cryptsetup-reencrypt`, to convert a non-encrypted filesystem to be encrypted to a `dmsetup` type of plain dm-crypt encrypted filesystem?